# I am making an app like tinder. I cannot link database info to my addToFavorite function to then send them to Favorite page

Tags: reactjs, data-layers, tinder

//Database is hardcoded and looks like this:

const db =[

```
{name: "pantaloni",
id:'1',
imgUrl: "https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/V/0/1/p/1930/026/800/2/w/1280/1930026800_6_1_1.jpg?ts=1608226801975"},

{name: "geaca",
id:'2',
imgUrl: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/38/b3/54/38b354027a74d5d39bec89a5c8b1eb48.jpg"},

{name: "bluza albastra",
id:'3',
imgUrl: "https://resense.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/bluza-dama-voal-verde-maneca-ampla-giulia-scaled.jpg"},

{name: "bluza",
id:'4',
imgUrl: "https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/V/0/1/p/8741/271/712/2/w/1280/8741271712_6_1_1.jpg?ts=1609850127999"}
```

];

//Then the function is :

```
function TinderCards(name, imgUrl,id) {
const [{Favorite}, dispatch] = useStateValue()
        console.log('this is' ,Favorite)
        const addToFavorite = () =>{
        dispatch({
            type:"ADD_TO_FAVORITE",
            item:{
                imgUrl:imgUrl,
                name:name,
                id:id
            }
        })
        };
```

//Linked to the like button:

```
function clickEvent(){

    swipe('right');
    addToFavorite()
}
```

//And when i click like everything is empty objects ->image:
[Console output is empty objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yntOE.png)